# java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected when update date

Tags: java, sql, oracle

Below is my sql statement in Java DAO. When I try to update the checkin and checkout date I got an error says

> java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was
>   found where a numeric was expected.

Do I need to convert the checkin and checkout from string to date using simpledateformat? If yes, how to insert in the sql statement.

***HTML***

```
 <form>
<input type="date" id="checkin" class="form-control" >
<input type="date" id="checkout" class="form-control" >
</form
```

**SQL**

```
CREATE TABLE "HOMESTAY"."BOOKING" 
  ( "BOOKINGNUM" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
   "CHECKIN" DATE, 
   "CHECKOUT" DATE, 
   "NUMOFDAYS" NUMBER(*,0), 
   "TOTALCHARGES" FLOAT(10), 
   "BFAST" VARCHAR2(10 BYTE), 
   "CUSTIC" VARCHAR2(12 BYTE), 
   "ACCID" NUMBER, 
    CONSTRAINT "BOOKING_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("BOOKINGNUM")
```

**Java**

```
public void updateBooking(BookingBean bean) {


int bookingnum = bean.getBookingnum();
String checkin = bean.getCheckin();
String checkout = bean.getCheckout();
int numofdays = bean.getNumofdays();
float totalcharges = bean.getTotalcharges();
String bfast = bean.getBfast();
String custic = bean.getCustic();
int accid = bean.getAccid();


try {

    currentCon = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
    ps=currentCon.prepareStatement("UPDATE booking SET (checkin , checkout, 
    numofdays, totalcharges, bfast, custic,accid)values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");


    String s = checkin;
    Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(s);       
    String s1 = checkout;
    Date d1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(s1);

    ps.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(d.getTime()));
    ps.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date(d1.getTime()));
    ps.setInt(3,numofdays);
    ps.setFloat(4,totalcharges);
    ps.setString(5, bfast);
    ps.setString(6,custic);
    ps.setInt(7,accid);
    ps.executeUpdate();
   }

    catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("failed: An Exception has occurred! " + ex);
   }

    finally {
    if (ps != null) {
        try {
            ps.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        ps = null;
       }

    if (currentCon != null) {
        try {
            currentCon.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        currentCon = null;
    }
   }    

   }
```

Comment: Please post the `CREATE TABLE` statement for the `booking` table.  We need to see the column types in order to help you.  Also, you should be using a prepared statement, but let's start with the first question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sir I've updated the create table statement.

Comment: Question: Why does `BookingBean#getCheckin()` return a string, when in fact the underlying data is actually a date?

Comment: Learn to use parameters!  This will prevent unexpected syntax errors that arise when you munge query strings.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen because in Java, I declare the check in and checkout as String. Does this answer your question sir :((

Comment: The problem is that we have to feed some sort of date back to Oracle, and I don't know how to do this, given your Java code.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen let say I used the prepared statement. Wait I Update my question.

Comment: Show us the string dates, and give some sample data.  The other fields are not really an issue, just the dates.

Comment: That's **NOT** the syntax of an `UPDATE` in Oracle SQL. Just saying. Use `update booking SET checkin = ?, checkout = ?, 
    numofdays = ?, totalcharges = ?, bfast = ?, custic = ?, accid = ?`. Plus... shoudn't you have a search condition using a `WHERE`?

Answer (score 1):

It is happening because you are trying to pass Strings to your `update` statement, but it expects Date types on the fields `checkin` and `checkout`.

For your `update` statement, you should try using `PreparedStatement` to pass in parameters. It's much easier to read and to maintain [Here](https://www.javatpoint.com/PreparedStatement-interface) is a website with some useful examples.

Now for your `Strings`, there are two things you could do:

The first one is to change those `BookingBean` attributes to `Date` type.

The second option is to keep using your `Strings` and pass them as date to the `PreparedStatement` as the example below:

```
try {
    currentCon = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement stmt = currentCon.prepareStatement(searchQuery);
    stmt.setDate(1, java.sql.Date.valueOf("2018-11-08"));
    stmt.executeUpdate(searchQuery);

} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Ps. For the first option, just pass in the date attribute to the `stmt.setDate`

Also, [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp) is an example of how to write the `update` command correctly.

Comment: Good Answer, except that you are using the terrible old legacy class `java.sql.Date` instead of its modern replacement, `java.time.LocalDate`.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

Never use the terrible old legacy date-time classes such as `java.sql.Date`, `java.util.Date`, `Calendar`, and `SimpleDateFormat. Use their replacement, the modern *java.time* classes.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , LocalDate.parse( "2018-11-08" ) )
```

…and…

```
LocalDate localDate = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

## java.time

The [Answer by Krum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53212011/642706) is correct, except that it uses the terrible `java.sql.Date` class that was outmoded years ago with the adoption of [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). As suggested in that Answer, you should be using **smart objects rather than dumb strings** to exchange date-time values with your database.

Let’s tweak the [code presented by Krum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53212011/642706). Two changes: (a) Replace legacy classes with modern ones, and (b) parse the input string separately in case of faulty input.

```
java.time.LocalDate localDate = null ;             // Use the modern `java.time.LocalDate` class that years ago supplanted the terribly-designed `java.sql.Date` class.
try {
    localDate = LocalDate.parse( "2018-11-08" ) ;  // The java.time classes by default know how to parse strings in standard ISO 8601 format such as seen here.
} catch ( DateTimeParseException e ) {
    … // Deal with invalid input string.
}

try {
    currentCon = ConnectionManager.getConnection() ;
    PreparedStatement stmt = currentCon.prepareStatement( searchQuery ) ;
    stmt.setObject(1, localDate ) ;                // As of JDBC 4.2, we can directly exchange java.time objects with a database via the `setObject` and `getObject` methods.
    stmt.executeUpdate( searchQuery ) ;

} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace() ;
}
```

And for retrieval.

```
LocalDate localDate = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).